# Failover cluster Alert Automation

Tags: arrays, powershell, cluster-computing, hashtable

In a high-availability environment (two DCs, Primary and Standby) with 50 clusters. Each cluster has 5 to 6 nodes in it. I want to ensure all the nodes in every cluster is "Online" (State) and running in "Primary" (OwnerNode). Any node that shows otherwise has to be noted.

I'm using arrays to store the required information in a `foreach` loop. The problem is, it is taking too long to compile. I want to complete it sooner.

```
$Clusternodes= * some 50 elements *
$Standbynodes= * some 50 elements *

foreach ($cluster in $Clusternodes) {
    $NotOnline += Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $Cluster |
                  where {$_.State -ne "Online"} |
                  Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
    foreach ($node in $Standbynodes) {
        $Standbys += Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $Cluster |
                     where {$_.OwnerNode -eq "$node"} |
                     Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

`Get-clustergroup -Cluster $Cluster` returns 5 to 6 entries in every cluster. The output contains three columns Name, OwnerNode, State.

I'm storing every entry in an array based on its state (whether it is running or not) and owner node (whether in primary or secondary DC). Hence, I want four arrays. While the former is easy, the latter isn't. As that itself is another two arrays with 50 odd elements in each. Hence I used hashtables for it as mentioned below. However, when I tried the below code it always returns an empty array.

```
$Clusternodes = * some 50 elements *
$Standbynodes = * some 50 elements *
$Primarynodes = * some 50 elements *
$pr = @{}
$sb = @{}
$Standbynodes | ForEach-Object { $sb[$_] = $true }
$Primarynodes | ForEach-Object { $pr[$_] = $true }

$RunninginPrimary    = @()
$NotRunninginPrimary = @()
$RunninginStandby    = @()
$NotRunninginStandby = @()

foreach ($cluster in $Clusternodes) {
    $c = Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $Cluster

    $NotRunninginStandby += $c | Where-Object {
        ($_.State -ne "Online") -and ($sb.ContainsKey($_.OwnerNode))
    } | Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State

    $NotRunninginPrimary += $c | Where-Object {
        ($_.State -ne "Online") -and ($pr.ContainsKey($_.OwnerNode))
    } | Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State

    $RunninginStandby += $c | Where-Object {
        ($_.State -eq "Online") -and ($sb.ContainsKey($_.OwnerNode))
    } | Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State

    $RunninginPrimary += $c | Where-Object {
        ($_.State -eq "Online") -and ($pr.ContainsKey($_.OwnerNode))
    } | Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
}
```

Comment: `Get-Clustergroup -cluster $cluster` - returns three columns Name,OwnerNode,State and 5-6 entries. from there I have to choose Filter if State is not equal to Online and OwnerNode shouldn't be any item in $Standbynodes array.

Comment: Im a little confused,
So you have a DC ->50 Clusters->5-6 Nodes->
Meaning about 250 nodes....But the way you are running the script is looks like your running every Node against every cluster. meaning instead of a total of 250 runs you are getting 12,500 runs.....

Answer (score 0):

You query each cluster multiple times. To speed up your code query each cluster just once, store the result in a variable, and use that variable in the rest of the loop. You may also want to replace the nested loop that iterates over `$Standbynodes` with a hashtable lookup.

```
$Clusternodes = ...
$Standbynodes = ...

$sb = @{}
$Standbynodes | ForEach-Object { $sb[$_] = $true }

$NotOnline = @()
$Standbys  = @()

foreach ($cluster in $Clusternodes) {
    $c = Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $Cluster

    $NotOnline += $c | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Online" } |
                  Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
    $Standbys  += $c | Where-Object { $sb.ContainsKey($_.OwnerNode) } |
                  Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
}
```

Comment: I have never used that particular command but couldn't we use background Jobs or Runspaces to make it drastically faster? Only mentioning it because nobody else did and I am wondering why no one did.

Comment: @RohinSidharth That might help too, but AFAICS the biggest issue with the OP's code is the nested loop with the repeated `Get-ClusterGroup` calls.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It reduced my compile time. however, `{ $sb.ContainsKey($_.OwnerNode) }` doesn't work. There are four nodes running on standby servers, but the array is empty.

Comment: @SivaThilak Did you verify that `$sb` contains the correct keys? Please update your question with your modified code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have modified the code based on new requirements a bit. But still, I couldn't find a way to populate my array.

Comment: @SivaThilak Did you verify that the hashtables contain what they should? Is the value of `$c` what you expect? Try running the code from the loop body for a single cluster and without appending to arrays (output directly). Do you get any output from that? I'm unable to provide further help without seeing sample input.

Comment: I've tried to lessen the amount of work within loop and it paid off. It's okay. I figured it on my own. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using workflow.

```
workflow clusterCheck {

     $Clusternodes= * some 50 elements *
     $Standbynodes= * some 50 elements *

    foreach -parallel ($cluster in $Clusternodes) {
        $NotOnline += Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $Cluster |
                  where {$_.State -ne "Online"} |
                  Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
        foreach -parallel ($node in $Standbynodes) {
                  $Standbys += Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $Cluster |
                  where {$_.OwnerNode -eq "$node"} |
                  Select-Object Name,OwnerNode,State
        }
    }
}
```

Source:- [Scripting guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics/)